# требует ли PostGIS интернет

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Нужен ли интренет для работы PostGIS?
Нужно использовать его на сервере без доступа к сети.
По сути будет использована только функция st_distance.

Comment: Нет, не‌‌​​‌‌‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌‌‌‌​‍​‌‌‌‌​​​‌‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​‌‌​‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​​​​‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​​‌​​‍​‌‌‌‌​​​​​‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​‌‌​‌ нужен.

Comment: Спасибо!  сайту надо длиииинный комент